# Spring Request as MultipartFile with JSON and Image not converting JSON to POJO

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, spring-annotations

I'm attempting to POST with jquery ajax to Spring Rest Controller an image and object data.
Original implementation of this method only posted the json data which was converted to my object.  I'm now attempting to post an image along with the json.  The image data is binding the the image in my controller method.  The json data is not being converted.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buildKit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public KitView buildKit(@RequestParam(value = "kitData", required = true)
KitTagIventoryDataList inventoryData, @RequestParam(value = "image", required = false)
MultipartFile image, @ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME)  KitTagCommand command) {
```

results in an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [com.blah.blah.webapp.spring3mvc.controller.KitTagIventoryDataList]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Changing the method signature to use @RequestPart instead of @RequestParam for the json/object portion of the request
results in no error, but the KitTagInventoryDataList object contains null values for all properties.

The request payload being posted with jquery ajax:

```
    -----------------------------22184201846440
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="kitData"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"serialId":"E20020839511008814907AB5","note":"box of notes","data":[{"id":"39212","qty":"0"},{"id":"39215","qty":"0"}]}
-----------------------------22184201846440
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG
```

Like I said mapping to @RequstBody and posting only the json/object data (no image) worked.

Thoughts?  At this point, I feel like I'm missing some dumb little detail.

Answer (score 0):

We don't send plain images in `RestFul applications`. We encode them first to `base64`, then you send it to your backend. Afterward, use

`byte[] image = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imagejson);`

to decode the image.

Also, don't pass your image as parameter, use `@RequestBody` instead.